# How to solve Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Models\Domain]?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to add a Factory to help increment my test coverage on some controllers. I've been using Factories with no issues till now, where I find no reason for this message and I can't figure out what is different from the rest of the factories, which are working perfectly.

The error is:

```
1) GuestBusinessControllerTest::it_presents_a_domain_home
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Models\Domain].
```

I reference the useful files as follows:

My [Controller Test](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/blob/add-test-coverage-with-domain-factory/tests/unit/controllers/Guest/GuestBusinessControllerTest.php) trying to use the Factory (Through a trait)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class GuestBusinessControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;
    use CreateBusiness, CreateDomain;

    // ...

    /** @test */
    public function it_presents_a_domain_home()
    {
        $domain = $this->createDomain();

        // ...
    }
}
```

The [trait using the factory](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/blob/add-test-coverage-with-domain-factory/tests/helpers/CreateDomain.php)

```
<?php

use App\Models\Domain;

trait CreateDomain
{
    private function createDomain($overrides = [])
    {
        return factory(Domain::class)->create($overrides);
    }

    // ...

}
```

The [factory definition](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/blob/add-test-coverage-with-domain-factory/tests/factories/factories.php#L50)

```
// ...

$factory('App\Models\Domain', function ($faker) {
    return [
        'slug'     => str_slug($faker->sentence(3)),
        'owner_id' => 'factory:App\Models\User',
    ];
});

// ...
```

I'm using ["laracasts/testdummy": "~2.0"](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/blob/add-test-coverage-with-domain-factory/composer.json#L60)

```
// ...

    "require-dev": {
        // ...
        "laracasts/testdummy": "~2.0",
        // ...
    },

// ...
```

*Sidenotes:*

> Yes, I did `composer dump-autoload` (Else, the error message would be different)
>
> I tried to define the factory in another helper file, and `dump-autoload`. (Just in case)
>
> I also tried renaming my model, thinking that `Domain` might be a conflicting keyword, but that seems not to be the issue.

How may I solve this error?

Comment: How about defining your factories as advertised? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#model-factories.

Comment: Good hint, but still, [just tried](http://laravel.io/bin/l5mPV) but the error persists the same.

Comment: Also tried removing [laracasts/testdummy](https://github.com/laracasts/TestDummy) as factories and faker are included in L5.1, but still same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Found the problem**

I was all the time thinking I was working with the file `tests/factories/factories.php` since I was using `laracasts/testdummy`.

It turns out (probably since the migration to L5.1, but not sure), I was now using `database/factories/ModelFactory.php` which I one day updated with my old factories, but never removed the `tests/factories/factories.php` and thus, editing it for new changes was worthless.

Now I've removed this file and kept a single factory file sticking to Laravel 5.1 solution out of the box.