# Laravel Database Factory Files not being called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, factory

I'm trying to test a model I've created, and I'm getting the error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default]
>   [App\Company].

Here's what my very simple model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function incidents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Incident::class);
    }
}
```

here's the factory:

```
<?php

$factory->define(\App\Company::class, function () {
    return [
        'name' => 'ACME Company'
    ];
});
```

and the setup method in my unit test that's throwing the error:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class CompanyModelTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp()
    {
        factory(\App\Company::class)->create();
    }
```

When I run the test I get this:

```
laradock@63912b4222e6:/var/www/laravel$ vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 5.5.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 528 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) CompanyModelTest::testCompanyName
InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\Company].

/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:126
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2280
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:139
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:106
/var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:84
/var/www/laravel/tests/CompanyModelTest.php:13
```

So far I've tried the suggestions on [this other Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421287/laravel-5-2-unable-to-locate-factory-with-name-default) about the same error, and [also this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558098/how-to-solve-unable-to-locate-factory-with-name-default-app-models-domain).

I've tried moving my new factory into the ModelFactory.php file that's there by default and I've tried using `defineAs()` instead of define.

I've cleared the cache and run `composer dump-autoload` as suggested in other posts around the web.

I've dumped out the contents of `FactoryBuilder::definitions` which is empty, and that's what's causing the exception to be thrown.

I've confirmed that none of the factory files in `database\factories` directory are being called with debug code & a line that would cause a parse error.

Why aren't those files being called as per the documentation?

Comment: Look in your `composer.json` file. In the `autoload` section you should see `"classmap": [ "database" ]`. Is that present?

Comment: @jszobody Yes, it's present. `"autoload": {"classmap": ["database"] ...`

Comment: typo: use `$factory->define()` instead of `$factory->defineAs()` and delete question since its typo question...

Comment: Thanks @Kyslik, the fact I didn't get an error about the missing parameter is just another reason why I can say they're not getting called ;-) I've fixed it now.

Comment: no problem, Artisan.

Comment: Have you had a solution to this? Facing the exact same issue and did all the steps you wrote down.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation the TestCase was wrong class.

```
class CompanyModelTest extends TestCase
```

Which TestCase do you extend? I had

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

Instead of Laravel's own. Now it is working!

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

Make sure you extend the correct TestCase class.